# fetch() and XMLHttpRequest GET does not work for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Userscript, which works absolutely fine. However, I have recently converted it into a Chrome Extension - which partially works. The only things that aren't working, for the Chrome Extension, are `fetch()` and `XMLHttpRequest GET`.

There are no errors in the console, and I made sure to include the URL, which I am trying to request to, in the manifest.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "WallpaperUI",
  "version": "0.23",
  "description": "Customize your Steam Profile more effectively.",
  "icons": { "128": "UILogo.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches": ["https://steamcommunity.com/id/*","https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "WallpaperUI.user.js"]
    }
   ],
  "permissions": [
    "https://steamcommunity.com/*",
    "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

And my JS:

```
fetch('https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=XXXXXXXXXX')
    .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
})
    .then(function(text) {
    console.log('Request successful');
    parseHTML(text);
})
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```

Comment: Try performing the fetch or XMLHttpRequest from a background script instead of a content script.

Comment: Modern Chrome [disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) so do it in the background script.